# Get LD1 values when applying LDA with CV = true in R

Tags: r

We wanted to see whether the recorded EEG data would be a good classifier to classify participants into group A or B.

I used the `LDA` function in the `MASS` package in `R` for a linear discriminant analysis. To make sure the model would be generalizable, we added a leave-one-out cross validation (`CV = TRUE`). All of this worked very well.

Now I would like to visualise this classification based on the discriminant scores. More specifically, show both groups on the x-axis and the discriminant scores on the y-axis. Something like this: [classification based on discriminant scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKjI2.jpg)

However, when applying `CV = TRUE`, it is not possible to use the `predict` function on the LDA object to generate **LD1 values**. Also, no **coefficients of linear discriminants** are returned (which could be used to calculate the discriminant scores myself (based on these links: [What are “coefficients of linear discriminants” in LDA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87479/what-are-coefficients-of-linear-discriminants-in-lda) and [Discriminant functions](https://app.displayr.com/Dashboard?id=8c523d80-60ed-46f6-ac0a-79853974424d#page=6253cfb7-39e2-4e2e-812b-6c0a52069a0d))).

When I remove the `CV = TRUE`, I can use the `predict` function afterwards and get the **LD1 values** (i.e. discriminant scores) needed for the visualisation. However, my classification results differ depending on whether or not I apply the leave-one-out cross validation. For example, when using `CV = TRUE`, a lower number of participants would be classified in the correct group. So if I would plot the data based on the results of the linear discriminant analysis without leave-one-out cross validation, it would not correspond to the results I would describe.

My question is whether there is a way to get the **LD1 values** or the **coefficients of linear discriminants** when applying `CV = TRUE` to the `LDA` function of the `MASS` package?
Or if someone knows another option to produce a plot similar to the one I added above?

Comment: when applying leave one out cross validation you are training and evaluating as many models as there are observations - for which one would you like to extract the LD1 values? I would report the LOOCV error rate and plot the LD1 values fitted on all the data.

Comment: Thanks @missuse, that makes sense. It's the first time I am applying LDA (and also LOOCV) and because I got an overall accuracy rate of prediction at the end, I thought it might be possible to plot it. Thanks for your help!